# Airflow DAG :Tasks followed by branching

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Airflow version: 2.1.1

[image: DAG]

I have a DAG where it processing 3 tables in a for loop. First, task-1 (GCS load) for all 3 tables are done, then branching for all 3 picks up and marked success. However after branching next task is done only on table B. Tasks for other tables are just skipped.

Code :

```
    for table in table_list:
        tableName = table["source_table_name"]
        partition = table["partition"]
        gcs_table_location = gcs_location + client_instance_name + "/" + tableName
        bronze_table_location = bronze_location + tableName
        silver_table_location = silver_location + tableName

        gcs_load = DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator(
            gcp_conn_id=var_gcp_conn_id,
            task_id=client_instance_name + "_gcs_load_" + tableName,
            main="xyz.py",
            region=var_region,
            project_id=var_project_id,
            cluster_name=cluster,
            arguments=[sqlserver_host, user, password, database, tableName, gcs_table_location],
            dag=dag)
        fork = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id='branching' + tableName,
            python_callable=get_option,
            provide_context=True,
            dag=dag)
        bronze_load = DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator(
            gcp_conn_id=var_gcp_conn_id,
            task_id=client_instance_name + "_Bronze_Load_" + tableName,
            main="abc.py",
            region=var_region,
            project_id=var_project_id,
            cluster_name=cluster,
            arguments=[gcs_table_location, bronze_table_location, client_instance_name],
            dag=dag)
        silver_load_from_bronze = DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator(
            gcp_conn_id=var_gcp_conn_id,
            task_id=client_instance_name + "_Silver_Load_" + tableName,
            main="pqr.py",
            region=var_region,
            project_id=var_project_id,
            cluster_name=cluster,
            arguments=[bronze_table_location, silver_table_location],
            dag=dag)
        silver_load_from_gcs = DataprocSubmitPySparkJobOperator(
            gcp_conn_id=var_gcp_conn_id,
            task_id=client_instance_name + "_SilverLoad" + tableName,
            main="uvw.py",
            region=var_region,
            project_id=var_project_id,
            cluster_name=cluster,
            arguments=[gcs_table_location, silver_table_location],
            dag=dag)

        start >> gcs_load >> fork >> bronze_load >> silver_load_from_bronze >> end
        start >> gcs_load >> fork >> silver_load_from_gcs >> endrk >> bronze_load >> silver_load_from_bronze
```

Based on the branching, I want it get processed for all the table in my for loop.

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you define the `branchingtableA` (for B and C as well)?

Comment: @bruno-uy  please find the code here : https://imgur.com/a/YGJNaSJ

Comment: I'll take a look, but can you please edit your question and include that as text to simplify the next user to read through it? Thanks.

Comment: @bruno-uy added

Comment: Seems the problem is in your `get_option` function (from `fork = BranchPythonOperator`). Can you add the code to the question? Seems you're not returning the proper values or you hardcoded the next tasks to use the table B.

Comment: correct, I solved it by passing parameter to branching operator. Logs at individual task level helped me to rectify this, I could explicitly see what each of my branch operator returned. Thank you.